# Looking for Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse Luna installed on my computer. I installed Eclipse Neon, and when I first ran it, a window opened with the list of all the plugins installed on Luna, and it asked me if I wanted them installed on Neon. By mistake, I clicked on no. And of course now, it's not asking me anymore.
So how do I do to get back this window? 
[image: window]
I tried the import application install wizard but I couldn't progress:
[image: window]

Comment: Well I tried. I deleted the folder and recreated it. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via *File* -> *Import.*

Select *Install*, then *From Existing Installation*

[image: Eclipse install from existing installation]

After browsing to an old Eclipse installation folder (Kepler in my case), you can choose which plug-in's to import.

[image: Eclipse install from Kelper]

Comment: It shows me Luna on the list but it is disabled because "a more recent version is already installed".

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Eclipse allows me to browse to a folder where an old version of Eclipse is installed (Kepler in my case), and shows the missing plugin's. I'll add the screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Will this install the plugins in their old version, or will it look for the respective newer versions of those plugins?